# Ionic v4 infinite scroll is still visible even if all data is fully loaded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll, ionic4

This is my first ionic application.

I am adding an infinite scroll to my ionic page:

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    //this.getOrders(0, this.pageSize);
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this.getOrders(0, this.pageSize++);
        this.orders.push(this.orders[i]);
      }

      infiniteScroll.target.complete();
    }, 500);
  }
```

And here is the html:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingText="Loading Data">
   </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

The problem is when scrolling down and all data is loaded, the loader is still visible and request is made to database.

No errors at the console.

Answer (score 1):

when all data is loaded you need add this

```
infiniteScroll.target.disabled = true;
```